# Pass multiple sets of variables to theme function

Tags: 7, theming

If I want to loop through multiple sets of theme variables in my custom theme template, how do I define them in my theme function and pass them to hook_theme?

For instance, in my case, I'm generating an email body to send via drupal_mail(), and the body will contain a list of spa openings. I want to iterate through each set in the mail (the same way views templates iterate over views rows). I have my theme function defined like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'my_module_mail' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'service_name' => NULL,
        'time' => NULL,
        'therapist' => NULL,
        'booking_link' => NULL,
      ),
      'template' => 'templates/my-module-mail',
    ),
  );
}
```

and I can pass one set of variables to the template just fine like so:

```
foreach ($available_openings[$tid['tid']] as $mail_opening) {
  $variables = $mail_opening;
  $body = theme('my_module_mail', $variables);
}
```

but what I want to do is pass an array of the variables array so that in my template can do something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($openings as $id => $opening): ?>
  <div class="<?php print $classes_array[$id]; ?>">
    <?php print $opening; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What do I need to change to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

And, the general rule of "post a question and that helps you figure it out yourself" applies here yet again.

All I did was modify my theme hook like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'my-module-mail' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'openings' => array(
          'service_name' => NULL,
          'time' => NULL,
          'therapist' => NULL,
          'booking_link' => NULL,
        ),
      ),
      'template' => 'templates/my-module-mail',
    ),
  );
}
```

and fill my $variables array like so:

```
  // Loop through all openings for this category.
    foreach ($available_openings[$tid['tid']] as $mail_opening) {
      $variables['openings'][] = $mail_opening;
    }
    $body = theme('my_module_mail', $variables);
    // Define mail parameters.
    $params = array(
      'subject' => t('Your Available Openings'),
      'body' => $body,
    );
    // Send the mail.
    drupal_mail('my-module-mail', 'featured_openings', $entity->mail, language_default(), $params);
```

and it works like a charm.